# ¿Como solucionar el siguiente error en c#?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ClasesBase
{
    public class TrabajarPrestamo
    {




        public static void AgregarUPrestamo(Prestamo oPrestamo)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ClasesBase.Properties.Settings.Default.conex);

            // comando de consulta
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into Prestamo 
                             (PRE_Numero,
                              CLI_DNI,
                              DES_Codigo,
                              PER_Codigo,
                              PRE_Fecha,
                              PRE_Importe,
                              PRE_TasaInteres,
                              PRE_CantidadCoutas,
                              PRE_Estado) values 
                              (@n, @dn, @codD, @codP, @fechP, @imp, @ta, @cuo, @est)";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cnn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", oPrestamo.Pre_numero);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni==null?DBNull.Value:oPrestamo.Cli_dni);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : oPrestamo.Cli_dni);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codD", oPrestamo.Des_codigo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codP", oPrestamo.Per_codigo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechP", oPrestamo.Pre_fecha);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imp", oPrestamo.Pre_importe);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta", oPrestamo.Pre_tasaInteres);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuo", oPrestamo.Pre_cantidadCuotas);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@est", oPrestamo.Pre_estado);



            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Prestamo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Prestamo'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Al parecer el error va hacia la tabla prestamos de la base de datos, el cual la clave primaria del pre_numero es identyty

Comment: si la key de la tabla es PRE_Numero y asignas un valor que ya existe obtendras ese mensaje, quizas debas realizar un UPDATE. Si la columna es identity no tienes que asignarla, la db la generara automaticamente

Comment: Básicamente el error te dice que No se puede insertar llaves duplicadas, por lo tanto, revisa cuál es el campo identity y dejas que el sql server lo genere

Answer (score 2):

Si el campo `PRE_Numero` es `identity` no debes asignarlo, sino que recuperas el valor usando el `SCOPE_IDENTITY` y el `ExecuteScalar()`

Algo como esto

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    cnn.Open();

    string query = @"insert into Prestamo 
                     (CLI_DNI,
                      DES_Codigo,
                      PER_Codigo,
                      PRE_Fecha,
                      PRE_Importe,
                      PRE_TasaInteres,
                      PRE_CantidadCoutas,
                      PRE_Estado) values 
                      (@dn, @codD, @codP, @fechP, @imp, @ta, @cuo, @est);
                      SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dn", oPrestamo.Cli_dni == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : oPrestamo.Cli_dni);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codD", oPrestamo.Des_codigo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codP", oPrestamo.Per_codigo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechP", oPrestamo.Pre_fecha);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imp", oPrestamo.Pre_importe);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta", oPrestamo.Pre_tasaInteres);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cuo", oPrestamo.Pre_cantidadCuotas);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@est", oPrestamo.Pre_estado);

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());  

    oPrestamo.Pre_numero = id;

}
```

Comment: Ahi comente la asignacion del campo PRE_numero, y agregue el executeScalar y el Scope identity, pero ahora me da error en el excecuteScalar.

InvalidOperationException was unhandled
ExecuteScalar requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es cerrada.

Comment: no estas realizando el Open(), en el ejemplo lo puse ni bien comienza el using del SqlConnection

Comment: Listo ahora me sale el siguiente error en el ExecuteScalar.
 There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: valida que la cantidad de parametros que defines coincide con las columnas, el @n debes quitarlo

Comment: Ya pude solucinar los problemas muchas Gracias Leandro te agradezco